# lambda can't have 2+ return values?

Tags: python, lambda

```
>>> def itself_and_plusone(x):
...     return x, x+1
... 
>>> itself_and_plusone(1)
(1, 2)

>>> (lambda x: x,x+1)(10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

why? and workaround with lambda? not by

```
>>> (lambda x: (x,x+1))(10)
(10, 11)
```

because it returns a tuple(or list..) and unpacking the tuple would be required

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without the parentheses it is interpreted as follows:

```
((lambda x: x),x+1)(10)
```

This fails because the second `x` is outside the lambda expression. And even if `x` were defined, it would still fail because you can't use a tuple as if it were a function.

This simple variation shows what is going on:

```
>>> x=42
>>> (lambda x: x,x+1)
(<function <lambda> at 0x00000000022B2648>, 43)
```

Notice that the 43 is because the `x` in the outer scope is used, not the `x` in the lambda function.

The correct way to write it is `lambda x: (x,x+1)`. This does indeed, as you point out, return a tuple, but so does your original function:

```
>>> type(itself_and_plusone(10))
<class 'tuple'>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, the tuple is implicit; python imagines the parenthesis for you when it sees the comma in the expression; it does this for any expression, not just when returning from a function:

```
>>> 10, 10
(10, 10)
```

But in your lambda example, you have to make them explicit, because python sees the whole expression as a new tuple (containing a lambda and a `x + 1` expression):

```
>>> (lambda x: x, 10)
(<function <lambda> at 0x10f331b90>, 10)
>>> lambda x: x, 10
(<function <lambda> at 0x10f331aa0>, 10)
>>> lambda x: (10, 10)
<function <lambda> at 0x10f314ed8>
```